# Sample AJAX call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Trying to do a simple AJAX call (teaching myself). I have a `.txt` file in same folder as `html`. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#poo").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); //stop submit
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "data.txt",
                    data: "", 
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#foo").html(data);
                        document.getElementById("foo").style.display = 'block';
                        alert('hey');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <form id="poo">
            <input type="text"> </input>
            <input type="submit"> </input>
        </form>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div style='display: none;'>
            <p id="foo">this shows</p>
            </div>
            <a href="page.html">Start Over</a>


    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? Are you running this on a server or just your local computer?

Comment: yes, on my chrome console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` for the first line `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: is jquery present at all? This error is typical when jquery is not found.

Comment: Are you running an HTTP server? Chome doesn't like it when you send ajax requests from a local file.

Comment: The jQuery was not added, I honestly didn't know too. Thank you. I also was running from a local file. Opening in Safari instead worked. Thanks to everyone in this comment thread for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a convenience function that loads remote files via AJAX and uses `.innerHTML()` to load it into any elements in your jQuery selector.

```
// Does the exact same thing as the entire block of code you wrote..
// These jQuery methods are chainable so you can do this in 1 statement.

$("#foo")                // Contains the DOM reference, 
                         // so no need to use getElementById().
    .load("data.txt")    // Loads "data.txt" into "#foo". 
    .show();             // Makes "#foo" visible.
```

Relevant:

- [jQuery selectors and method chaining](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/)
- [jQuery `load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [jQuery `show()` method](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

---

Per your comments, you had some other issues.

You said you weren't sure if jQuery was loaded. jQuery is just javascript, so you include it in `<script></script>` tags. The easiest way is to use [jQuery's CDN](https://code.jquery.com/). Click on the link, then choose the version and format you want. There will be a pop-up containing the script tag, just copy it into the page, preferably before any other Javascript you have on the page. If you're not sure which version/format to use, **v1.x, minified** is the way to go.

---

You mentioned that you were running it locally. The problem is, Javascript isn't supposed to have direct access to your filesystem. It will attempt to request the file over the `http` protocol, without having server software you can only request files over the `file://` protocol.

There are zillions of topics on this all over the internet, but to solve it you should install a server. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) is a good one and it's cross platform. Download that and your application will work in all your browsers. It will work in your browsers when you upload it to a server as well

Comment: Thanks this helped! I also had to open in Safari to not encounter any issues given from my browser (see original question comments).

Comment: @ceuskervin - I've updated the answer with all the relevant information you need to solve your problems. If I've helped feel free to hit the checkmark by my answer. :)

Comment: @Pamblam- thank you for your detailed answer. it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the `dataType: "text"`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
        $("#foo").html(data);
        document.getElementById("foo").style.display = 'block';
        alert('hey');
    })
```